# Some results are null when passing Dictionary<string, int[]> from JS to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, hashmap

I am puzzled by this, help would be very much appreciated:

So I have a button that when you click on it, it calls the function **bulkUpdate**.

I created a **dictionary** in that js function with the format: 1 key and 2 values.

When I verify the values in js, **ALL the values in dictionary are NOT null** as you can see by the following printscreen:
[the dictionary in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMFys.png)

However, when it reaches the controller by an ajax call, some of the values are null. I noticed that this only happens with keys that start with a letter instead of a number. 
[the dictionary in the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/808n4.png)

Does anybody know why this happens and how I can solve it?

JS:

```
function bulkUpdate(e, id){

    var dictionary = {};

    var el = $("#grid"+id),
        grid = el.data("kendoGrid"),
        dataSource = grid.dataSource;

    var data = grid._data;

    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var foodID = grid._data[i].ID;
        var extraQuantityBoxe = $("#extraAmmount" + foodID).val();
        var takeStorageBoxe = $("#takeFromStorage" + foodID).val();

        dictionary[foodID] = new Array();
        dictionary[foodID].push(extraQuantityBoxe);
        dictionary[foodID].push(takeStorageBoxe);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'BulkUpdate',
        data:  {values : dictionary},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#grid"+id').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        },
        error: function () {
            var notification = $("#notification").getKendoNotification();
            var notificationBaseHeight = 100, notificationLineHeight = 25;
            notification.show({
                message: '@Resources.warnGenericError'
            }, "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult BulkUpdate(Dictionary<string, int[]> values)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int[]> pair in values)
            {
                string key = pair.Key;
                int[] value = pair.Value;

                Guid foodID= new Guid(key);

                FOODS food = _db.FOODS.Find(foodID);
                food.INGREDIENT_EXTRA_QUANTITY = value[0];
                food.TAKE_FROM_STORAGE = value[1];
                food.INGREDIENT_TOTAL_QUANTITY = food.INGREDIENT_QUANTITY + value[0] + value[1];
                food.UPDATED_AT = DateTime.Now;
                food.UPDATED_BY = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["username"].ToString();
            }

            _db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(false, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to easily verify this solution, but it seems related to how the data is being passed to the controller from the AJAX call, and then how it is being deserialized on the controller side.  Try stringifying the *dictionary* prior to sending it.

Change the *data* line in your AJAX call, trying it a couple ways...

Just stringifying the dictionary:

```
data:  {values : JSON.stringify(dictionary)}
```

Or, the whole POST body:

```
data:  JSON.stringify({values : dictionary})
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I had already tried that solution and it only returned to the controller an array with two strings, one saying "action" and the other value saying"controller". Still, thanks for answering

Comment: Did you try adding the [FromBody] to your parameter definition?  So your method signature would be BulkUpdate([FromBody] Dictionary<string, int[]> values).

Comment: Yes, still only appears "action" and "controller"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieRP1.png

Comment: The only way it works is if I add a number before the GUIDs that start with a letter, something like newFoodID = "" + 0 + foodID ... really strange isn't it

Comment: Hmm, yes very strange!

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed since the beginning, that if the key is a Guid that starts with a number, it works, but if it is a Guid that starts with a letter, it doesn't work. I've fixed adding a random number but that is a bad practice.